# On symbolic constants and memory allocation

Tags: c

When one declares

```
int my_number = 300;
```

Compiler allocates enough memory to store exactly 1 integer and writes bit representation of 300 in that space.

When one *instead*

```
#define MY_NUMBER    300
```

Whenever `MY_NUMBER` is mentioned, value is simply replaced with 300.

I understand that symbolic constants are not variables and wonder what happens from the stand point of memory allocation? In event a symbolic constant is used, how much memory is used to keep track of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero. The `#define`-d constant is not a real constant: it does not have a type, and it does not occupy *data* memory. Its occurrences in your program are replaced with the literal `300`, that's all. The constant value does occupy *program* memory in the binary code of your program, but it's not the kind of memory to which you could take a pointer without getting into the undefined behavior territory.

Comment: You should be comparing to constants, not 'normal' variables. When using constants, a compiler might choose to produce the exact same binary code as with #defines, or it might choose to emit a variable reference. With non-const varibles, for *some* scenarios the compiler can produce the same results as #define, but some will require link-time code generation and "whole program" optimization.

Comment: @snemarch I wrote (and subsequently deleted) a comment about compiler's possible optimization of the two into identical code. I deleted my comment because the OP deleted his comment with the question.

Comment: yeah, the comment I was replying to disappeared as I hit enter. I'll leave the comment, even if it seems strangely out of place :)

Comment: Hey guys, i removed the comment since dasblinkenlight updated the main answer to include the answer. Thank you both

Comment: Why, who's to say what is a "real" constant and what isn't? I say that only `#define`d constants are "real" constants, and all other constants are fakes and wannabes. Furthermore, you cannot say with absolute certainty that the actual coded value will occupy *program* memory, because there exist architectures that do not have load-immediate instructions, which means that all data, even hard-coded constants, are separate from code. (If I remember well, the IBM 360 was one such architecture.)

Comment: @MikeNakis You are correct: I think it's the absence of "load immediate" that caused an infamous bug of the early Fortran compiler, where you could replace a constant with another value. The format of the Q&A, however, forces me to take certain shortcuts, and skip details that many non-assembly programmers would find non-essential.

Comment: Yes, of course, I understand. I am just being a jackass here.  C-:=

Answer (score 1):

Kinda depends on the machinery, compiler and perhaps optimization.  The 300 will probably end up in some read-only section.  It may be an immediate operand in the .text, (code) or a value in .rdata, (constant data) sections.  On some embedded systems with speed optimization, it may even get copied at startup time from ROM to a RAM section where access is faster.

Usually, it will be a machine-width word value for each time it is used.

Essentially, the memory space is allocated at compile-time and forms part of the executable image.